# convert column in a matrix to a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I convert a column in a matrix to a list in Python? 
E.g. 
convert

```
test = [['Student','Ex1','Ex2','Ex3'],['Thorny','100','90','80'],['Mac','100','90','80'],['Farva','100','90','80']]
```

to

```
Student = ['Thorny','Mac','Farva']
```

Please advise.

Comment: `[x[0] for x in test[1:]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Student = list(zip(*test))[0][1:]

where 

>>>list(zip(*test))

[('Student', 'Thorny', 'Mac', 'Farva'),
 ('Ex1', '100', '100', '100'),
 ('Ex2', '90', '90', '90'),
 ('Ex3', '80', '80', '80')]
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Also, raw code snippets may be identified as "low quality posts" and deleted. I'm seeing this post from that queue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, the most compact way I could come up with:
Student = [y[0] for y in test]

The 0 can be changed to what you want of course.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use numpy for its indexing:

```
import numpy as np
convert_test = [['Student','Ex1','Ex2','Ex3'],['Thorny','100','90','80'],['Mac','100','90','80'],['Farva','100','90','80']]
convert_test = np.array(convert_test)
print(convert_test[:,0])
```

> array(['Student', 'Thorny', 'Mac', 'Farva'], dtype='U7')

Comment: I'm not sure that easiest is the right adjective here.

Comment: Fair enough. I like @Stepan Filonov's answer better. Good use of vanilla python.